# Corporate network interfering with Azure Active Directory login

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a UWP app which tries to grant access to the user by logging in to Azure Active Directory. In some instances it has been noticed that when the user is connected to the Corporate network, user isn't able to login.

Error like: "Cannot connect to the service. Service is currently unavailable" is displayed on the login prompt.

However, if the user goes off the corp network and then tries to login, s/he is able to do so.

My question: Why is corp network interfering with AAD login and how can we make sure that AAD login works with/without the corp network.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do users have trouble logging in to AAD using the web while behind the corporate firewall, or just your app? Do you know if your company uses ADFS?

Comment: @Josh Users are having trouble logging in through the app. The login works as expected elsewhere. I am not sure if my company uses ADFS.

Comment: Hi,Could tell me what UWP are you using ?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I hope you are asking about the target version. Target version is Windows 10 (Build 10240).

Comment: Usually, Within a same Network Environment, you can connect Azure AD service from any where if the configuration is OK. But your issue looks like just be with that UWP APP, I think we should do a deeper test to find the cause. So, Can you login Azure with Internet browser and another UWP App, such as OneNote?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to login to Azure throw browsers and OneNote.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Today, I faced the same issue through Outlook. It hasn't happened before. So, is it something wrong at the environment level? If so, how to figure it out and how to fix it?